# PostgreSQL select and aggregate

Tags: postgresql, select, stored-procedures, sum

all!
I have the following scenario:
1. a pretty complicated SELECT statement. I need the first n rows from its result set, call it $sql with a joins and multiple WHERE clauses.
2. an aggregating SELECT statement where I use all the results from the complicated select statement, which looks like:

```
SELECT SUM(a), (SELECT DISTINCT....) etc.
```

Currently the implementation looks so, that the two steps are done separately in a perl code.

1. first a cursor is made "DECLARE cur CURSOR WITHOUT HOLD FOR $sql'
2. then the first n hits are fetched.
3. then the summary call comes interpolating the whole $sql into the statement:

   ```
   SELECT SUM(foo) AS sum1 
   FROM A, ($sql) AS B
   WHERE A.doc=? AND A.id=B.id
   ```

That is expensive, $sql takes <1 sec and done twice. Obviously I would like to avoid the second call if possible.
So, I would like to write a function that takes the $sql ( that is generated dynamically ) and the number of records to return,
returns the records but stores the whole result set to avoid doing the query again. The result set is >6000 rows.

However, being not strong in PL/pgSQL I can not really picture it as a stored procedure. Shall I create a temp. table with the result set of the firs query and use it later in the second step? Or better to do the select and the summary in one step and store the result in a temp. table? Programmatically I'd chose the second, but again, I need an advice on that.

And I would greatly appreciate any code sketch, too, to get a better grip on PL/pgSQL in general and to see how to solve this kind of 'SELECT and aggregate' kind of problem, returning two kinds of values.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: You can try using `SELECT INTO` and create temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Check the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

> When an aggregate function is used as a window function, it aggregates over the rows within the current row's window frame. An aggregate used with ORDER BY and the default window frame definition produces a "running sum" type of behavior, which may or may not be what's wanted. To obtain aggregation over the whole partition, omit ORDER BY or use ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING. Other frame specifications can be used to obtain other effects.

Suppose `t` is the dynamic query:

```
select *
from (
    select *,
        sum(foo) over () as the_sum,
        row_number() over(order by bar) as rn
    from t
) s
where rn < 3
;
 foo | bar | the_sum | rn 
-----+-----+---------+----
   1 | a   |       6 |  1
   2 | b   |       6 |  2
```

`t`:

```
create table t (foo int, bar text);
insert into t (foo, bar) values
(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c');
```